# Why does scikit-learn implement ROC on a per-observation basis instead of over the entire model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I understand the principles behind the ROC curve on theoretical grounds, but its implementation in sklearn confuses me. I understood the ROC to plot the the ratio of TPR to FPR as a specific kind of model takes on different threshold values for what counts as a TP--a view that chimes [with this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-roc-and-auc-curves-a05b68550b69). In this understanding, each point on the ROC curve is the (FPR, TPR) coordinate for a model type at a particular threshold. Thus, a logistic regression (say) can be compared with (say) a random forest classifier for a particular dataset, with each ranging over different parameters.

However, in sklearn, each point of the ROC curve corresponds to an *observation* in a single model--ie:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
scores = np.array([0.47, 0.62, 0.53, 0.49, 0.76, 0.57, 0.97, 0.95, 0.46, 0.69])

fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y, scores)
sns.lineplot(x = fpr, y = tpr, ci = False)

plt.plot(fpr, tpr)
plt.plot([0,1], [0, 1], '--')
```

[image: TPR over FPR]

It is as if each classification is treated as a kind of mini-model in its own right. If so, I don't grasp how the TPR/FPR can be legitimately called a rate, as there is only one value and no way to calculate the FPR and TPR using the formulae:

TPR = TP/TP+FN

FPR = FN/FN+TP

By the same logic, I can't see how the predicted model probabilities (the scores) function as thresholds when they're only valid for a single observation.

I'm probably missing something fundamental here and would be grateful for any intuitions concerning what it is?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind; I see my error now. For anyone coming to this post similarly confused, my mistake was this. The sklearn `roc_curve` does, in fact, plot a different range of thresholds for a specific model type. The probabilities supplied to it (i.e. the scores) give it the range of thresholds it needs to cover; the thresholds outputed from `roc_curve` are the different thresholds the model can take for making a positive classification. Thus, one point of the ROC curve will be the TPR and FPR calculated for a specific threshold value; the another point will be for a different value etc. Makes sense once you think about it.